# Modificar un callback asíncrono añadiendo un singleton thread

Tags: java

he revisado en patrón observador asincrono en : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-synchronous-callbacks-java/

Lo he probado y funciona bien. Ahora bien , quiero modificarlo para revisar si en cierto directorio aparece un archivo determinado y si aparece puedo terminar el proceso presionando "Enter". Estoy realizando la revisión constante de los archivos de mi directorio dentro de un **while** y sospecho que estaría creando varios hilos haciendo la misma tarea "buscando si existe el archivo "archivo1.txt" en mi directorio". Por ello he hecho un cambio usando un singleton que funciona pero no estoy seguro si es lo mejor que se puede hacer.

Código de GeeskgorGeeks.

```
// Java program to illustrate Asynchronous callback 
  
interface OnGeekEventListener { 
  
    // this can be any type of method 
    void onGeekEvent(); 
} 
  
class B { 
  
    private OnGeekEventListener mListener; // listener field 
  
    // setting the listener 
    public void registerOnGeekEventListener(OnGeekEventListener mListener) 
    { 
        this.mListener = mListener; 
    } 
  
    // My Asynchronous task 
    public void doGeekStuff() 
    { 
  
        // An Async task always executes in new thread 
        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() 
            { 
  
                // perform any operation 
                System.out.println("Performing operation in Asynchronous Task"); 
  
                // check if listener is registered. 
                if (mListener != null) { 
  
                    // invoke the callback method of class A 
                    mListener.onGeekEvent(); 
                } 
            } 
        }).start(); 
    } 
  
    // Driver Program 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
  
        B obj = new B(); 
        OnGeekEventListener mListener = new A(); 
        obj.registerOnGeekEventListener(mListener); 
        obj.doGeekStuff(); 
    } 
} 
  
class A implements OnGeekEventListener { 
  
    @Override
    public void onGeekEvent() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Performing callback after Asynchronous Task"); 
        // perform some routine operation 
    } 
    // some class A methods 
}
```

Sin embargo , me pregunto si en el bloque puedo crear un singleton que instancie una vez un thread y luevo evaluarlo dentro de un while hasta que se cumpla una cierta condicion.

```
// My Asynchronous task 
    public void doGeekStuff() {
     // TODO
}
```

De la siguiente forma:

```
// My Asynchronous task 
    public void doGeekStuff() {

     ThreadSingleton mysingleton = ThreadSingleton.getInstance(mListeners);

        while (System.in.available() == 0){
            mysingleton.run();
        };
}
```

Donde la estructura  de mi singleton sería:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class ThreadSingleton extends Thread {

    private static ArrayList<myEventListener> mListeners = null;

    private static  ThreadSingleton myOnlyThread = new ThreadSingleton();

    private ThreadSingleton(){}


    public  static ThreadSingleton getInstance(ArrayList<myEventListener> temp){
        mListeners = temp;
        return myOnlyThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        if(mListeners != null){
            //System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            String[] fileList = file.list();
            assert fileList != null;
            for(String name:fileList){
                // System.out.println(name);

                if (name.equals("archivo1.txt")){
                    for (myEventListener e:mListeners){
                        e.reportingSomeStuff();
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Esto con el **objetivo** de no ir creando un sin fín de hilos y consumir la memoria. Está bien esta solución o debo considerar algo diferente? ¿Qué puedo cambiar y/o investigar? Gracias por la ayuda.

Pdt: Los archivos completos del código en consulta están en este repositorio.

https://github.com/MarcoYcaza/Java/tree/master/CallbackTask

Comment: llamas a  mysingleton.run(); ? cuando deberias de llamar a explicitamente a  mysingleton.start() para ejecutar el hilo. run() es el methodo implementado.

Comment: LLamo a run dado que este método ejecuta el mismo thread instanciado , si llamo a start intentaría crear un nuevo thread y daría error.                                     https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-thread-start-and-thread-run-in-java/

Comment: Si llamas por fuera Run el hilo nunca se ejecuta. Pero en que parte del codigo llamas a start para que se ejecute el Thread?

Comment: Hola , no es estrictamente necesario llamar a start. Ambos metodos cumplen con iniciar el funcionamiento del hilo , la dieferencia es que start crea una nueva instancia del thread cada vez que se le llama. En cambio run() crea una vez la instancia del hilo y al llamarlo de nuevo no crea otro hilo sino que devuelve el hilo actualque está corriendo.    ``` while (System.in.available() == 0){
            mysingleton.run();
        }; ```  Pdta : Con run() si corre el código mas no con start() (lanza error java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Comment: No quiero insistir. Si llamas a Run llamas al metodo no a la ejecución del Thread. cuando extendes de Thread o implementas desde Runnable tenes que llamar a start para que se inicie el Thread. De lo contrario solo estas llamando al metodo. Eso lo podes probar facilmente. Pone un Thread.sleep de 20 segundos al metodo Run y vas a ver que si llamas a Run tenes que esperar para continuar.

Comment: He probado lo que me comentas de la siguiente forma:
public class playground {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(()->{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Hello");
        });
        myThread.run();
        //myThread.start();
    }
}
Este es el enlace que me ayuda.Gracia
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-thread-start-and-thread-run-in-java/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111808/discussion-between-marco-ycaza-lengua-and-toto).

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la ayuda brindada. Reemplacé con el método start par a iniciar un nuevo hilo dado de que con run() no hacía efecto al solo devolver el main thread.

Link recomendado: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-thread-start-and-thread-run-in-java/

```
private void checkingMyInnerDirectory() {

        ThreadSingleton mysingleton = ThreadSingleton.getInstance(mListeners);
        mysingleton.start();

}
```

En el archivo Singleton:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ThreadSingleton extends Thread {

    private static ArrayList<myEventListener> mListeners = null;

    private static final ThreadSingleton myOnlyThread = new ThreadSingleton();

    private ThreadSingleton(){}


    public  static ThreadSingleton getInstance(ArrayList<myEventListener> temp){
        mListeners = temp;
        return myOnlyThread;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        /*try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        if(mListeners != null){
            boolean token = true;
            while(token){
            //System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            String[] fileList = file.list();
            assert fileList != null;

                for(String name:fileList){
                    // System.out.println(name);
                    if (name.equals("archivo1.txt")){
                        for (myEventListener e:mListeners){
                            e.reportingSomeStuff();
                        }
                        token = false;
                    }

                }
            }


        }

    }
    
}
```

Lo demás está en el repositorio:

https://github.com/MarcoYcaza/Java/tree/master/CallbackTask